# semanage & restorecon -R are not applying recursively as I expect

Tags: centos, selinux

My VPS cloud provider is one of those that provides most of the storage under a `/data` disk, so the webroot would actually be at `/data/www` instead of `/var/www` , and there is a symbolic link from `/var/www` to `/data/www` so that default Apache configs work.

The server started out with SELinux disabled, and Wordpress and Postfix are running fine.  So when I enabled SELinux to permissive mode, I see lots of errors via Cockpit.  I am new to SELinux, and I did these:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/data/www(/.)?"
sudo restorecon -R -v /data/www
```

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/data/www/html(/.)?"
sudo restorecon -R -v /data/www/html
```

After the first pair of commands, I was surprised that the `httpd_sys_content_t` type didn't propagate to all the contents.  So I tried the second pair, and it was the same.  Only the 2 directories: `/data/www` and `/data/www/html` are set with the desired type.

I have probably misunderstood the use of semanage and restorecon.  Help please.  The goal is to set the correct types on those things in `/data`.

For completeness, I am doing it again, and copy pasting the contiguous lines, below. (Is my use of `-m` instead of `-a` correct when repeating the `semanage` command?)

```
[~]$ sudo semanage fcontext -m -t httpd_sys_content_t "/data/www/html(/.)?"
[sudo] password for johnsmith:
[~]$ sudo restorecon -R -v /data/www/html
[~]$ ls -lZ /data/www/html/
total 24
drwxrwxr-x.  3 apache apache system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 4096 Jul 14 15:15 foo
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache system_u:object_r:default_t:s0  430 Mar  2 18:51 index.php
-rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 1402 Mar  4 11:00 bar.gif
drwxr-xr-x. 12 apache apache system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 4096 Mar  3 16:29 pmadir
drwxr-xr-x. 10 apache apache system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 4096 Feb 24 12:05 sendy
drwxr-xr-x. 10 apache apache system_u:object_r:default_t:s0 4096 Jun 11 06:48 wordpress
[~]$
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not being set recursively. Add the output of `ls -lZ /data/www/html` to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have missed a `*` (wildcard) there:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/data/www(/.*)?"
```

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!  Sorry, I deserve a kick.  I have [posted a follow-up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598589/quick-way-to-set-selinux-context-for-many-labels-centos-8), because I learned about `semanage fcontext -l | grep -i /data` , so I can see that I have many more rules to add.  And I am asking whether there is a faster way.