# Quick way to set SELinux context for many labels - CentOS 8

Tags: centos, selinux

I am using one of those cloud VPS providers that provide most of their storage on the /data disk, so my webroot is at `/data/www` instead of `/var/www`. And there is a symlink so that Apache works fine with default config.

I think the goal is to copy all the rules under `/var/www` and create the same rules except `/var/www` is changed to `/data/www`.  Is there a way to do it quickly?

```
[~]$ sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep -i /var/www
/var/www(/.*)?                                     all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
/var/www(/.*)?/logs(/.*)?                          all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0
/var/www/[^/]*/cgi-bin(/.*)?                       all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0
/var/www/apcupsd/multimon\.cgi                     regular file       system_u:object_r:apcupsd_cgi_script_exec_t:s0
... many more ...
```

I only know how to do them one by one, by giving:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/data/www(/.*)?"
sudo restorecon -R -v /data/www
```

This takes care of the first rule.
Is there a way to do it fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for *substitute* by chance? 
From [`man semanage-fcontext`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-fcontext.8.html):

> **OPTIONS**
>
>   `-e EQUAL`
>   ,
>   `--equal EQUAL`
>     Substitute target path with sourcepath when generating default label. 
>     This is used with
>     `fcontext`
>     . 
>     Requires source and target path arguments. 
>     The context labeling for the target subtree is
>     made equivalent to that defined for the source.
>     ︙
>
> **EXAMPLE**
>
>   Substitute
>   `/home1`
>   with
>   `/home`
>   when setting file context
>
> ```
> # semanage fcontext -a -e /home /home1
> # restorecon -R -v /home1
> ```

Demo:

```
mkdir -p /data/www2/html
touch /data/www2/html/foo
semanage fcontext -a -e /var/www /data/www2
restorecon -R /data/www2
ls -lhZ /data/www2/html/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 0 15. Jul 15:31 foo
```

Comment: It works, thank you!  This is exactly what is needed for the case of transplanting a directory to a data disk.